# Where is the function "gsl_matrix_view_array" defined in the source?

Tags: gsl

I looked at an example for solving a system of linear equations using GSL and it contained this line:

```
gsl_matrix_view m = gsl_matrix_view_array (a_data, 4, 4);
```

I looked in the GSL source code and found the declaration for `gsl_matrix_view_array` inside the file `gsl_matrix_double.h`. However I couldn't find the definition anywhere.

Where could the definition of `gsl_matrix_view_array` be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from elsewhere that `gsl_matrix_view_array` is defined in `gsl/matrix/view_source.c` using macros.

Answer (score 0):

if you look inside the file: /usr/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_double.h   (this is the location from ubuntu 22.04), you will find this definition:

```
....
typedef struct
{
  gsl_matrix matrix;
} _gsl_matrix_view;

typedef _gsl_matrix_view gsl_matrix_view;

...
```